# AND / OR logic in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to select from `tblReportDescription`. I have a column `reportType` that I am using in my logic in the WHERE statement.

I would like to `SELECT`  ALL `reportType = 1` where the length of the column `descriptionCode` is equal to 1 or is equal to 4.

I would also like to `SELECT` all `reportType = 2` WHERE the length is less then 3 or that is greater then 5.

I'm attempting this logic with this line of code here:

```
SELECT * FROM tblReportDescription
WHERE (reportType = 1 and LEN(descriptionCode) = 4 OR LEN(descriptionCode) = 1) OR (
reportType = 2 and LEN(descriptionCode) < 3 OR LEN(descriptionCode) > 5
)
```

It seems like the `OR reportType = 2 and LEN(descriptionCode) < 3 OR LEN(descriptionCode) > 5` logic is interfering with the `reportType = 1` logic. The reason for this is that one of the rows that are return has a `descriptionCode` length of 7 when it should only be returning lengths of 4 and 1.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT *
into tblReportDescription
FROM
(
    values 
    (34, 'Report tile 1', '3223', 1),
    (21, 'Report tile 2', '2', 1),
    ( 3, 'Report Title 3', '344322', 2),
    (13, 'Report Title 4', '34', 2),
    ( 8, 'Report Title 5', '1511', 1),
    ( 9, 'Report Title 6', '15', 2),
    (19, 'Report Title 7', '4444', 2),
    (14, 'Report Title 8', '6662566', 1)
  ) v ( id, description, descriptionCode, reportType )

SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblReportDescription
WHERE
    (
        reportType = 1
        and
        LEN(descriptionCode) = 4
        OR
        LEN(descriptionCode) = 1
    )
    OR
    (
        reportType = 2
        and
        LEN(descriptionCode) < 3
        OR
        LEN(descriptionCode) > 5
    )
```

and here is an example of the select that is returned:

| id | description | descriptionCode | reportType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | Report Title | 3223 | 1 |
| 21 | Reports Title 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Report Title 3 | 344322 | 2 |
| 13 | Report Title 4 | 34 | 2 |
| 8 | Report Title 5 | 1511 | 1 |
| 9 | Report Title 6 | 15 | 2 |
| 14 | Report Title 8 | 6662566 | 1 |

If the query is correct I should NOT be seeing row Id 14 where length description code = 7 since it's a report type of 1 which should only return lengths of 4 and 1

How can I correct my `WHERE` statement so it's not interfering with one another?

Here is a [database](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae45fa677e9323df6e1a6b1731cf6cb7) fiddle with my examples

Comment: Looks like missing parentheses. Try: `WHERE (condition1 AND (condition1a OR condition1b)) OR  (condition2 AND (condition2a OR condition2b))` In your code, with `WHERE (condition1 AND condition1a OR condition1b)` it does the AND first, then the OR whereas you want to force the OR to be done first, then the AND

Comment: I formatted your SQL to be more readable and if you put each `WHERE` clause predicate and operators on their own-line and then align the parentheses it's very easy to tell where mismatched conditions are - or when `AND` and `OR` are used incorrectly. In this case, you have an `OR` after an `AND` which is almost never what people actually want.

Comment: Personally I'd instead have `WHERE CASE WHEN reportType = 1 AND LEN( descriptionCode ) IN ( 4, 1 ) THEN 1 WHEN reportType = 2 AND LEN( descriptionCode != 4 ) THEN 1 END`

Comment: @Dai `LEN( descriptionCode != 4 ) ` should be `LEN(descriptionCode) NOT IN (3,4,5)` I think? (Its > & < , not <= & >=). Why do you prefer using a `case` to evaluate the logic?

Comment: @DaleK I prefer using `CASE` for expressions that need to handle mutually-exclusive-and-exhaustive choices as it better signifies intent, and makes it more obvious when a case is missing. (I know that `CASE x WHEN y` and `CASE WHEN x = y` are different constructs, but the intent is there. That said, it's annoying how SQL doesn't let you have inline multi-statement expressions.

Comment: @Dai does it cause any sargability issues?

Comment: @DaleK As far as I can tell, using `CASE` [only affects SARGability in nested views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171337/case-statement-and-sargability-specific-use-case) - in this case (no pun intended) I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: @DaleK I jsut saw my typo about `LEN( descriptionCode != 4 )` - sorry, it should be `LEN( descriptionCode ) NOT IN ( 3, 4, 5 )`, yes. Derp :)

Comment: @stepheniok can you please check the answer, I added a answer using UNION ALL as you can maintain each in different queries. Normally we use this in reporting as it is very easy to maintain ad troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need additional brackets to ensure the `OR` gets evaluated correctly

```
SELECT *
FROM tblReportDescription
WHERE (
    reportType = 1 AND /* --> Additional bracket */ (LEN(descriptionCode) = 4 OR LEN(descriptionCode) = 1) /* <-- Additional bracket */ 
)
OR (
    reportType = 2 AND /* --> Additional bracket */ (LEN(descriptionCode) < 3 OR LEN(descriptionCode) > 5) /* <-- Additional bracket */
);
```

Because:

> When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, the AND operators are evaluated first. You can change the order of evaluation by using parentheses.

Reference: [Logical Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Although as Dai points out the logic can be simplified to avoid those `OR`s (below). But its still good to understand how `AND`/`OR` logic works:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblReportDescription
WHERE (
    reportType = 1 AND LEN(descriptionCode) IN (4,1)
)
OR (
    reportType = 2 AND LEN(descriptionCode) NOT IN (3,4,5)
);
```

FYI your original query is equivalent to the following, where only one of the 4 conditions needs to be true:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblReportDescription
WHERE (reportType = 1 and LEN(descriptionCode) = 4)
OR LEN(descriptionCode) = 1
OR (reportType = 2 and LEN(descriptionCode) < 3)
OR LEN(descriptionCode) > 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Here you can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. I suggest `UNION ALL` because you know that the given data set does not include duplicates. But if the data set is subject to change better to use `UNION` as it filters Duplicates.

Make note that `UNION ALL` is better in performance than `UNION` due to that `UNION` filters duplicates.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tblReportDescription
 WHERE reportType = 1 
 AND LEN(descriptionCode) IN (1, 4)

 UNION ALL -- better use this. (you can use UNION as well)

 SELECT * 
 FROM tblReportDescription
 WHERE reportType = 2 
 AND (LEN(descriptionCode) < 3 OR LEN(descriptionCode) > 5)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: A good answer explains itself in addition to having working code. Specifically you should explain why using `UNION ALL` helps and under what circumstances you would use it over regular AND/OR logic.

Comment: The problem with `UNION` / `UNION ALL` to concatenate two mutually-exclusive results together is that you end-up needing to repeat the bulk of your `SELECT ... FROM...` query twice. So I agree with you in principle, but SQL's horrible and unnecessary verbosity makes this solution more painful to maintain.

Comment: Union with queries are easy to manage than nesting Predicates in a where clause. As if we use more OR statements inside a where clause it is very difficult to find which filter. But in  These types of queries, adding a one additional Colum with a value can be easily find out which query gives results when finding errors. 
 When you use EXCEPT OR INTERCEPT, you need to be more careful as it can have problems because of the columns you consider. 
This way is one possibility, it is the question owner who can tell which solution is better

Comment: @Dai Is logical operators maintainable ? How can we guarantee? as it can have many issues .

Comment: @Gudwlk That's a subjective issue - you raise some good points but I still feel that using a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` in this situation _doesn't feel right_ - and as I said, I don't like this approach because you need to repeat your query twice (I see you've been downvoted, that wasn't me, I did not downvote you).

Comment: I'm with Dai on this one, I would *only* use `UNION ALL` if I encountered performance issues with `OR` regular logic. I would never use that as an initial solution. Not only do you have to duplicate the query but you've separated out the logic into 2 branches which is more complex to comprehend. And it doesn't scale well if you have more than two `OR` branches. Also I would pretty much never use `UNION` - rather I would build a query that either doesn't contain duplicates or I would use `GROUP BY` or other relevant mechanisms to ensure I get the correct data.

Comment: @DaleK We as developers  show possibilities of different approaches with different technologies. it is about the correct way of obtaining the result.  If we get the correct answer, and if we have different solutions we get a chance to compare and learn thing. That is the purpose of supplying answers with different technologies. I have shown one possibility. Some others may show different approaches. Owner of the question has the freedom to select what technology to use. when it comes to comment any one can comment and show us some points. :)

Comment: @Gudwlk there are two problems with your previous comment 1) Using `UNION ALL` doesn't actually explain to the OP what they were doing wrong in the first place i.e. missing bracke43ts. And 2) While you present a different possibility of sorts you don't actually explain why and under what circumstances you would use it - so a beginner OP is left unsure about when this would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is different precedence for `AND`/`OR` operators.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

You should put brackets like this:

```
SELECT *
into tblReportDescription
FROM (values 
             (34, 'Report tile 1', '3223', 1),
             (21, 'Report tile 2', '2', 1),
             (3, 'Report Title 3', '344322', 2),
             (13, 'Report Title 4', '34', 2),
             (8, 'Report Title 5', '1511', 1),
            (9, 'Report Title 6', '15', 2),
            (19, 'Report Title 7', '4444', 2),
            (14, 'Report Title 8', '6662566', 1)
     ) v(id, description, descriptionCode, reportType)
SELECT * FROM tblReportDescription
WHERE reportType = 1 and (LEN(descriptionCode) = 4 OR LEN(descriptionCode) = 1)
OR reportType = 2 and (LEN(descriptionCode) < 3 OR LEN(descriptionCode) > 5)
```